# Reference Request: An operation preserving bijection from a magma to a group must be a group isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, magma

Let $M$ be a **magma** with a binary operation $*_M$ and let $G$ be a **group** with a binary operation $*_G$.

If $f$ is a bijection from $M$ to $G$ preserving the operation, 
that is, $f(m_1 *_M m_2)=f(m_1)*_G f(m_2)$, 
then $(M, *_M)$ is a group.

I think this theorem is a powerful tool of proving a magma is a group. Does anyone know which books talk about this topic?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for a book on? A book on magmas?

Comment: By requiring $f$ to be a bijection it follows immediately from a more general statement that pulling back group operation on a group $G$ to a set $S$ via a bijection gives you a group structure on $S$, which is in no way "powerful".

Comment: Further to @user10354138 's comment. Since a structure preserving bijection is an isomorphism.  Isn't this saying isomorphism to a group must be a group isomorphism?

Comment: This is simply “transport of structure”; if you have a bijection between two sets $X$ and $Y$, and an operation on one of them, then the bijection can be used to “transport” the operation onto the other set, and the two will then be isomorphic. What you have here is a bijection between $M$ and $G$, and “preserving the operation” means that the operation on $M$ is exactly the same as the transported operation of $G$. Therefore, the two structures are isomorphic, and in particular $M$ is a group. You won’t find it in any book because (i) there are few books on magmas; and (ii) it’s trivial.